# Stop debugging in Progress in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015. My solution was working properly but somehow it stopped working. Every time I am trying to run the solution it opens a pop-up and says stop debugging in progress. 
there were few solutions on stack overflow regarding my problem but they were not helpfull to solve my problem so please help me.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this problem coming for certain project or for all projects that in the VS?

Comment: No this is for certain project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reset the Visual Studio setting and restart the system and now its working fine.

> Tool > Import And Export Settings > Reset All Settings > No just Reset
>   Settings, overwriting  my current settings > Genrel

Answer (score 0):

Every now and then Visual Studio can get stuck or a bit buggy. First port of call when something like this happens to me and nothing has changed, I will shutdown Visual Studio and restart it to see if that cleared the problem.